# Implementing distance fucntion for dimensional and multi type data

Tags: java, twitter, cluster-analysis, elki

I'm using ELKI in java for clustering tweet's text in kmeans algorithm. Before clustering, I calculated similarity of tweet's text with tf-idf measure that it used for clustering.

```
 public void clustering(String file) throws FileNotFoundException {
    //Distance.calSim("after sorting.txt");
    similarity = MainElki.getSimilarity();
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new File(file));
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int k = 0; k < numCorpus; k = k + 20) {
        double[][] subArray = new double[20][20];
        subArray = getSubArray(k, k);

        DatabaseConnection dbc = new ArrayAdapterDatabaseConnection(subArray);
        Database db = new StaticArrayDatabase(dbc, null);
        db.initialize();
        SquaredEuclideanDistanceFunction dist = SquaredEuclideanDistanceFunction.STATIC;
        RandomlyGeneratedInitialMeans init = new RandomlyGeneratedInitialMeans(RandomFactory.DEFAULT);

        KMeansLloyd<NumberVector> km = new KMeansLloyd<>(dist, 3, 0, init);
        Clustering<KMeansModel> c = km.run(db);

        Relation<NumberVector> rel = db.getRelation(TypeUtil.NUMBER_VECTOR_FIELD);
        DBIDRange ids = (DBIDRange) rel.getDBIDs();
        strBuilder.append("\n******** subArray[" + k + "]" + "[" + k + "]");
        int i = 2;
        for (Cluster<KMeansModel> clu : c.getAllClusters()) {
            // K-means will name all clusters "Cluster" in lack of noise support:
            strBuilder.append("\n    #" + i + ": " + clu.getNameAutomatic() + "\n");
            strBuilder.append("    Size: " + clu.size() + "\n");
            strBuilder.append("    Center: " + clu.getModel().getPrototype().toString() + "\n");

            strBuilder.append("  Objects: ");
            for (DBIDIter it = clu.getIDs().iter(); it.valid(); it.advance()) {
                // To get the vector use:
                NumberVector v = rel.get(it);

                // Offset within our DBID range: "line number"
                final int offset = ids.getOffset(it);
                strBuilder.append(" " + (offset + k));
                // Do NOT rely on using "internalGetIndex()" directly!
            }
            i++;
        }
    }//end of for subArray
    writer.write(strBuilder.toString());
    writer.close();
}//end of clustering function
```

Now I'd like to use other feature of tweets in clustering (example hashtags, number of like, number of retweets, …). I know that I can define custom distance function in ELKI but all abstract class of distance function of ELKI is in one dataType ( example AbstractNumberVectorDistanceFunction) but feature of tweets is different : double for istance of tweet's text, int for number of like and retweets, String for hashtags.

```
 public class CustomizedDistance extends AbstractNumberVectorDistanceFunction    {
 @Override
public double distance(NumberVector arg0, NumberVector arg1) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
}

}
```

Is any way for writing customized distance function that calculate distance of tweet's text and then compute final distance by using other feature like number of like ?

Answer (score 1):

KMeans, as the name indicates, needs to compute the *means*.

This algorithm can only be used on vectors in R^d.

So by any means, if you *really* want to do this (kmeans doesn't work well on attributes with different scale!) you *will* have to convert all your attributes into numbers. Or use a different algorithm.

Comment: Do you have any example that I can work with it in elki that support multi type attribute?

Comment: No, I use only numerical data. I tried to look at the statistical reasons for "multi type" data, and it appears to be very very weak. So there doesn't appear to be a "sound" way of handling that, only "black magic", with results not better than random.

Comment: because of my research, I need to test that using other features can improving the result or not. It seems using all feature of tweets can help to clustering tweets.

Comment: Maybe. I don't think you can cluster Tweets in any useful way. But **if you want to use k-means, you *have* to satisfy it's R^d requirement**. Don't expect me to make k-means magically work on characters when you *need* real numbers to compute means...

Comment: No, I doesn't have to use kmeans. I wanna start with library that have better algorithm for clustering or topic detection in my dataset.

Comment: Library recommendations are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

K-means can only work on `NumberVector`s, there is *no* way around this.

For many *other* algorithms, this is possible. You would need to:

1. Implement a new data type `YourDataType` with multiple types of data
2. Implement a parser to load the data
3. Implement a `DistanceFunction<YourDataType>`

But as noted in Anony-Mousse's answer, k-means *can* only support `NumberVector`. It will not accept `YourDataType`. Because it cannot compute a mean on this data.

I would like to have support for this in ELKI, but I myself don't have the need for this; I don't see any good distance function for such data (there is Gower's; but it's not what I consider "good" - to be useful, it will require a lot of manual scaling, weighting, and such modifications for every data set again), and it's not clear how to optimize implementations for this scenario. So it is too low on my priority list to implement myself, but I appreciate well-designed pull requests.

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. Do you suggest that I implement a new data type and use other algorithms of ELKI or I write my algorithm?

Comment: Even if you write your own algorithm, you will *first* have to implement a data type to manage the data. So I'd first do this, then try some existing algorithms, then eventually add your own algorithm if necessary.